# Android No Break Space - how to?

Tags: java, android, whitespace, html-entities

I have a bug, where **only** on HTC Evo 4g text in EditText shows up with underscores instead of spaces Jack_Johnson, instead of Jack Johnson.  The data comes from a server.

How do I incorporate \u00A0 or &nbsp  into the code below?  Will that even fix my problem?

```
editName.setText(recipient.name);
```

Comment: thanks for question ^^, I only will do setText("\u00A0"); and works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
editName.setText(Html.fromHtml(recipient.name));
```

Answer (score 0):

So you actually want to unescape the exported from the server escaped special characters? If so, Html.fromHtml won't work, but you can use **StringEscapeUtils** from the apache commons lang library - http://commons.apache.org/lang/

Comment: Why would my problem only happen on a specific device model?  I get no underscores on any other device?  Is StringEscapeUtils reaaly what I need?

Comment: From what I get the text you currently set to your editText is:
`editName.setText("foo &nbsp bar"); `
Is that really the case? If so, you need StringEscapeUtils. If the text is:
`editName.setText("foo bar");`
I have completely no idea what's going on on this HTC Evo xD